# dynamic sorting in prisma and typed queries

Tags: typescript, orm, prisma

I'm trying to define a query in prisma at runtime, but getting stuck at the first hurdle.

so this works:

```
  const items = await prisma.styleTags.findMany({
    orderBy: {
      name: 'asc',
    }
  });
```

but when I try to separately define the query I get TS errors.

```
  const orderBy = {
    cname: 'asc',
  }
  const items2 = await prisma.styleTags.findMany({
    orderBy
  });
```

those two things *should* be identical? but somewhere deep in prisma's maze of automagically generated code...

```
Type '{ cname: string; priority: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Enumerable<StyleTagsOrderByWithRelationInput> | undefined'.
  Type '{ cname: string; priority: string; }' is not assignable to type 'StyleTagsOrderByWithRelationInput'.
    Types of property 'cname' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'SortOrder | undefined'.
```

from `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'SortOrder | undefined'.` I thought maybe I can just pass `orderBy: 'name'` but that fails too.

FWIW if i `@ts-ignore` the code works, but if prisma typechecking has to be ignored, then it serves little purpose.

my next step after that is to try to dynamically compose the `orderBy` from passed in parameters, but I need to get the basics above to work first.

Can someone suggest why this typechecking of prisma fails?

Comment: This is considering `cname` as string in `orderBy` object when you are creating `orderBy` object separately.

Comment: `const orderBy = {
    cname: 'asc',
  } as const` may help to stop typescript from inferring the `cname` as string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use these workarounds -

1. Wrap the `orderBy` with `as const` to stop `typescript` from inferring the
   order as string.
2. Use `Prisma.orderBy.asc` instead of "asc".

Answer (score 0):

This is my NextJs api endpoint logic:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import prisma from '@/lib/prisma';

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    const { _page, _limit, _sort, _order} = req.query;
    const limit = +(_limit ?? 20);
    const offset = (+(_page ?? 1) -1 ) * limit;
    const sort = (_sort ?? 'id').toString();
    const order = _order ?? 'asc';

    const orderBy = {[sort]: order};
    const userCount = await prisma.users.count();
    const users = await prisma.users.findMany({
        orderBy,
        skip: offset,
        take: limit
    });

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.setHeader('x-total-count', userCount);
    res.status(200).json(users);
}
```

I hope it will help